# Tic-Tac Toe (Tabular Method) for Integration by Parts

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-cd

I was able to complete the code, but I am wondering if there is a quicker or more efficient way to create this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,quotes}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

                \newcommand*{\myprime}{^{\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
                \newcommand*{\dprime}{^{\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
                \newcommand*{\trprime}{^{\prime\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}   
                \newcommand\df[4]{\(\displaystyle\int_{#1}^{#2}#3,d#4=\)}
                \newcommand\ex[1]{\textbf{Example #1:}}
                \newcommand\indef[2]{\(\displaystyle\int{#1}d{#2}=\)}
                
        
        
\begin{document}

    
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (a) at (-3,0) {\(u(x)\)};
            \node (b) at (-3,-1){\(u^{\myprime}(x)\)};
            \node (c) at (-3,-2){\(u^{\dprime}(x)\)};
            \node (d) at (-3,-3){\(u^{\trprime}(x)\)};
            \node (e) at (-3,-4){\(u^{iv}(x)\)};
            
            \node (f) at (3,0) {\(v(x)\)};
            \node (g) at (3,-1.5) {\(v^{\myprime}(x)\)};
            \node (h) at (3,-2.5) {\(v^{\dprime}(x)\)};
            \node (i) at (3,-3.5) {\(v^{\trprime}(x)\)};
            \node (j) at (3,-4.5) {\(v^{iv}(x)\)};
            
            \draw[latex-latex] node[below]{\(+\)}(a)--(g);
            \draw[latex-latex] (b)--(h)node[midway,above]{\(-\)};
            \draw[latex-latex](c)--(i)node[midway,above]{\(+\)};
            \draw[latex-latex](d)--(j) node[midway,above]{\(-\)};
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tic-Tac-Toe is a board game played on a 3 by 3 grid. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean Tabular Method often referred to as Tic-Tac-Toe for integration by parts

Comment: I am sure this can be done with `tik-cd`. It should never be needed to hard code that many coordinates.

Comment: I know, that is why I posted my code to see if someone has a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ways.

[image]

Using `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>={latex}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4cm, row sep=.5cm]
u\arrow[dr, <->, "+"] & v\\
u'\arrow[dr, <->, "-"] & v'\\
u''\arrow[dr, <->, "+"] & v''\\
u'''\arrow[dr, <->, "-"] & v'''\\
u^{iv} & v^{iv}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Using `positioning`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.5cm and 5cm]
\node(u0){$u$};
\node[below=of u0](u1){$u'$};
\node[below=of u1](u2){$u''$};
\node[below=of u2](u3){$u'''$};
\node[below=of u3](u4){$u^{iv}$};
\node[right=of u0](v0){$v$};
\node[below=of v0](v1){$v'$};
\node[below=of v1](v2){$v''$};
\node[below=of v2](v3){$v'''$};
\node[below=of v3](v4){$v^{iv}$};
\foreach \n/\s[count=\m] in {0/+,1/-,2/+,3/-}\draw[latex-latex](u\n)--node[above]{$\s$}(v\m);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Looping:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \p[count=\n] in {,','',''',^{iv}}{
        \node(u\n)at(0,-\n){$u\p$};
        \node(v\n)at(5,-\n){$v\p$};
    }
    \foreach \n/\s[evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n+1)] in {1/+,2/-,3/+,4/-}\draw[latex-latex](u\n)--node[above]{$\s$}(v\m);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```